# ASP .NET MVC3 emulate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, azure, emulation

I'm trying to get an ASP .NET 4 MVC 3 website into a web application with a roll to deploy it to azure. When I try to run it in emulator I get this:

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "INIConnect.Common.Infrastructure.Interfaces.IUser", name = "LoggedInUser".
>   Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>   Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, INIConnect.Common.Infrastructure.Interfaces.IUser, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

---

At the time of the exception, the container was:

```
Resolving INIConnect.Common.Infrastructure.Interfaces.IUser,LoggedInUser
```

I don't know what it means.... Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there dependency injection going on? Almost sounds like you're using DI to inject a class to use for your interface but that setup isn't being called. (pure guess)